# OBIEE - Using "IN" & "NOT IN" within Column Formula

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

Looking for some help here if I may.

I have a Variable Dashboard prompt, which when placed on a dashboard can be used to select Multiple Sites. This variable is called V_SITES.  Its list is built using a SQL statement which functions as expected.

I have entered the following into a Column Formula.

```
sum(Case
When "Folder_Heading"."SITES" IN (@{V_SITES}{'Site1','Site2','Site3'})
Then 1
Else 0
End)
```

This Works beautifully when I don't assign the Variable.
However as soon as I assign the Variable say ('Site1','Site2','Site3').

It fails, with the following message.

```
Error Codes: OAMP2OPY:OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P:OI2DL65P

SQL Issued: SELECT sum(Case When "Folder_Heading"."SITES" IN (Site1,Site2,Site3) Then 1 Else 0 End) FROM "Test_Cube"
```

I noticed that it loses those all important quotes (Site1,Site2,Site3)... If this is causing the issue, I don't understand why this is happening as I have told the V_SITES to be TEXT.

Please help!

Many Thanks

P

> EDIT: After loads of testing, I'm fairly confident that the problem is
>   Oracle is not wrapping my text in single quotes when building the sql
>   string...  Just need to figure out how to make it...

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had the same issue, and whilst Shakey's solution works, the real solution is to use ['@'] in the formula (From Oracle tech support: Formula Syntax to Populate Multi-Select Presentation Variable (Doc ID 2063624.1) )

```
sum(Case
When "Folder_Heading"."SITES" IN (@{V_SITES}['@']{'Site1','Site2','Site3'})
Then 1
Else 0
End)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the support document that you could add on your answer please?

Comment: Here is the link: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2063624.1

Answer (score 0):

OK Convinced this is an Oracle Bug...

This is my workaround in case anyone else comes up against this... However I'm very happy to be corrected if there is a better workaround or fix!

The issue was when OBIEE builds the SQL string it doesn't text qualify the Variable.
So I text qualified it myself by modifying the list of available values in the Parameter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHAR(39) || "TEST_CUBE"."FOLDER_HEADING"."SITES" || CHAR(39) s_1 FROM "TEST_CUBE" ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Only annoying thing is I now have ' at the start and end of every Value.

Hope this helps someone else.